# How are 'main' countries chosen during Debian/Ubuntu installation?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, debian, installer

When installing Ubuntu or Debian, there are a number of of standard options on the "Select your location" menu:

- Antigua and Barbuda
- Australia
- Botswana
- Canada
- Hong Kong
- India
- Ireland
- Israel
- New Zealand
- Nigeria
- Phillippines
- Singapore
- South Africa
- United Kingdom
- United States
- Zambia
- Zimbabwe
- other

What was the rationale of selecting exactly those countries as "main" ones, as opposed to others?

I don't reckon there are many users from Antigua and Barbuda as opposed to, say, China or Brazil, which are not on this list.

Comment: Just found the rationale; this is totally answerable!

Answer (score 5):

## Countries presented are based on language already selected

The selection process is laid out in [the README for `localechooser`](https://salsa.debian.org/installer-team/localechooser/blob/master/README) (used to [build debian-installer images](https://packages.debian.org/source/sid/localechooser)):

> The purpose of localechooser is to ask the person doing the
>   installation about his preferred language and country of "residence".
>   This information can be used to choose which language and country or
>   region to use during installation and set this language and country as
>   the default language and country after the installation.
>
> ...
>
> **The country choice question refines the country choice inherited from
>   the language choice**. It allows choosing any "country" in the
>   world. Depending on the language+country combination, this will be
>   used for setting a default locale or not (see below for details).

*(source: `localechooser` [README](https://salsa.debian.org/installer-team/localechooser/blob/master/README) (link to git blob), lines 4-26)*

And, more specifically:

> -always prompt the user (high priority) with a *short* list of all
>    countries for which a valid locale exists for this language
>    THIS LIST IS BUILT AT BUILD TIME for countrychooser, not on the fly
>    at install time. It is built only for languages which have a debconf
>    translation for countrychooser

*(lines 146-150, ibid)*

There is further detail on the process, which goes about selecting a language, location and finally locale.

In your example, I would presume that you have selected **English**, as those countries you have have a significant English-speaking presence.

---

<sup>credit to pabs and youpi in #debian-boot, who gave a brief overview of the process</sup>